# combine multiple CSS or JS files in OpenCart

Tags: javascript, php, css, opencart, opencart2.x

I want to Increase Page Speed in **OpenCart**. So, I want to combine multiple CSS or JS files in One file. but, JS & css files is added dynamic according to module enabled.

So, How can I make combine multiple CSS or JS files?

**From This**

```
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/common.js"></script>
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/flexslider/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>

<link href="catalog/view/javascript/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/stylesheet/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/flexslider/flexslider.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

**To This**

```
<script src="catalog/view/javascript/vwc43ljnyxgu4y/combined.js"></script>
<link href="catalog/view/theme/default/2hs3dfonugkz/combined.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [minify](https://code.google.com/p/minify/) this does the job well by piling all of them together.

You can use also `RequireJS` for Javascript files. `RequireJS` calls all the JS files from a specified path.

check that out here
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#jsfiles

Answer (score 1):

[Gulp](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) is a good tool to do what you're looking for. It can combine stylesheets, and javascript files and even do versioning which is great for cache-busting.

Taken from their official documentation:

## Getting Started

1. Install gulp globally:

```
$ npm install --global gulp
```

2. Install gulp in your project devDependencies:

```
$ npm install --save-dev gulp
```

3. Create a `gulpfile.js` at the root of your project:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

4. Run gulp:

```
$ gulp
```

Using Gulp in addition to [gulp-concat-css](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat-css) will allow you to do exactly what you need.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var concatCss = require('gulp-concat-css');
```

gulp.task('default', function () {
      return gulp.src('assets/**/*.css')
        .pipe(concatCss("styles/bundle.css"))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('out/'));
    });

(Note, I am in no way affiliated with Gulp, but use it on many of my own projects).